# Modifying control register in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

The following simple kernel module sets the 13th bit of the cr4 register (`CR4.VMXE`) once it is loaded and clears the bit on exit.

## vmx.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static inline uint64_t getcr4(void) {
    register uint64_t ret = 0;

    asm volatile (
        "movq %%cr4, %0\n"
        :"=r"(ret)
    );

    return ret;
}

static inline void setcr4(register uint64_t val) {
    asm volatile (
        "movq %0, %%cr4\n"
        :
        :"r"(val)
    );
}

static int __init init_routine(void) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    printk(KERN_INFO "VTX Test loaded: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));
    cr4 |= (1 << 13);
    setcr4(cr4);
    cr4 = getcr4();
    printk(KERN_INFO "cr4: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));

    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_routine(void) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    printk(KERN_INFO "cr4: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));
    cr4 &= ~(1 << 13);
    setcr4(cr4);
    cr4 = getcr4();
    printk(KERN_INFO "VTX Test exited: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));
}

module_init(init_routine);
module_exit(exit_routine);
```

## Makefile

```
obj-m += vmx.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

To run the module I use `make clean && make && sudo insmod vmx.ko && sudo rmmod vmx && sudo dmesg -c`. This sometimes gives me the following (expected) output

```
[ 2295.121537] VTX Test loaded: 1312736 (0).
[ 2295.121540] cr4: 1320928 (1).
[ 2295.123975] cr4: 1320928 (1).
[ 2295.123977] VTX Test exited: 1312736 (0).
```

And sometimes also the following:

```
[ 2296.256982] VTX Test loaded: 1320928 (1).
[ 2296.256984] cr4: 1320928 (1).
[ 2296.259481] cr4: 1312736 (0).
[ 2296.259483] VTX Test exited: 1312736 (0).
```

The second and third line in the secound output seem strange to me, because it seems like the modified control register cr4 has been reset after leaving `init_routine`. Additionally it is strange that in the first line the VMXE bit seems to be set, which doesn't really make any sense. Is this behavior normal? How can it be explained? Could there be another kernel module running which modifies CR4? This seems rather strange because I've seen several VTX implementations and they all set the VMXE bit in their initialization routine and clear the bit in their exit routine in the same fashion as in this module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is that the register is not modified on all CPU cores. To ensure that the modifications happen on all cores it seems to be enough to invoke `on_each_cpu`. Fixed code below, Makefile unchanged.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static inline uint64_t getcr4(void) {
    register uint64_t ret = 0;

    asm volatile (
        "movq %%cr4, %0\n"
        :"=r"(ret)
    );

    return ret;
}

static inline void setcr4(register uint64_t val) {
    asm volatile (
        "movq %0, %%cr4\n"
        :
        :"r"(val)
    );
}

static void setvmxe(void* info) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    cr4 |= (1 << 13);
    setcr4(cr4);
}

static void clearvmxe(void* info) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    cr4 &= ~(1 << 13);
    setcr4(cr4);
}

static int __init init_routine(void) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    printk(KERN_INFO "VTX Test loaded: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));
    on_each_cpu(setvmxe, NULL, 0);
    cr4 = getcr4();
    printk(KERN_INFO "cr4: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));

    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_routine(void) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    printk(KERN_INFO "cr4: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));
    on_each_cpu(clearvmxe, NULL, 0);
    cr4 = getcr4();
    printk(KERN_INFO "VTX Test exited: %llu (%u).\n", cr4, (unsigned char)((cr4 >> 13) & 1));
}

module_init(init_routine);
module_exit(exit_routine);
```

Comment: So, if it's a kvm problem, then probably better to report to the community. [Subscribe](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#kvm)

Comment: @AndyShevchenko The problem was not related to kvm.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the `kvm` module (and the associated `kvm-intel` or `kvm-amd`) kernel modules loaded. These modules already manage the processor's VT state, and are likely to be *very confused* if you start modifying it elsewhere.

Take a look at the [`arch/x86/kvm`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/arch/x86/kvm/) directory in the kernel source to get a sense of what already exists.

Comment: The problem is still present after unloading kvm with `sudo rmmod kvm-intel && sudo rmmod kvm`

Comment: As it turns out, I think one needs to ensure that the register gets modified on all CPU cores using the `on_each_cpu` function, which seems to fix my problem. I'm gonna have a closer look at it and post an answer later if it really is the solution I'm looking for.