# Linux Kernel Module: Setting CR4.VMXE does not persist

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm playing around with VMX on XUbuntu 16.04, but I'm running into some issues with setting the VMXE bit of CR4. The issue is that by the time my exit function is called, the bit is no longer set.

## vmmod.c

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

#define AUTHOR "me"
#define DESC "Test"

extern u64 read_cr4(void);
extern void write_cr4(u64 val);

static bool IsVMXEEnabled(void)
{
    return (read_cr4() >> 13) & 1;
}

static void SetVMXEEnabled(void* _val)
{
    bool val = *(bool*)_val;
    u64 mask = (1 << 13);
    u64 cr4 = read_cr4();

    if (val)
        cr4 |= mask;
    else
        cr4 &= (~mask);

    write_cr4(cr4);
}

static void LogVMXEState(void* info)
{
    (void) info;
    printk(KERN_INFO "CR4: %08LX\n", read_cr4());
}

static int __init init_(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "===================================\n");

    if (IsVMXEEnabled())
        printk(KERN_INFO "VMXE Is Enabled\n");
    else
    {
        bool new_vmxe_state = true;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Enabling VMXE\n");
        on_each_cpu(SetVMXEEnabled, &new_vmxe_state, 1);

        if (IsVMXEEnabled())
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "VMXE Has Been Enabled\n");
            on_each_cpu(LogVMXEState, NULL, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "VMXE Could Not Be Enabled\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "----------------------------------------\n");

    on_each_cpu(LogVMXEState, NULL, 1);
    if (IsVMXEEnabled())
    {
        bool new_val = false;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Disabling VMXE\n");
        on_each_cpu(SetVMXEEnabled, &new_val, 1);

        if (!IsVMXEEnabled())
            printk(KERN_INFO "VMXE Has Been Disabled\n");
        else
            printk(KERN_INFO "Couldn't disabled VMXE...\n");
    }
    else
        printk(KERN_INFO "VMXE Wasn't enabled?\n");

    printk(KERN_INFO "===================================\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

MODULE_AUTHOR(AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DESC);

module_init(init_);
module_exit(exit_);
```

## vmasm.S

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text

.global read_cr4
read_cr4:
    mov rax, cr4
    ret

.global write_cr4
write_cr4:
    mov cr4, rdi
    ret
```

## Makefile

```
obj-m += testmod.o
testmod-objs := vmmod.o vmasm.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

## Testing

```
$> sudo insmod testmod.ko && sudo rmmod testmod
```

## Output

```
[  607.459248] ===================================
[  607.459256] Enabling VMXE
[  607.459302] VMXE Has Been Enabled
[  607.459311] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.459315] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.459318] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.459321] CR4: 000426F0
[  607.459334] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.459336] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.459338] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.459373] CR4: 000426E0
[  607.473007] ----------------------------------------
[  607.473025] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473065] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473068] CR4: 000406F0
[  607.473072] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473074] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473078] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473080] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473103] CR4: 000406E0
[  607.473121] VMXE Wasn't enabled?
[  607.473129] ===================================
```

The output clearly shows that Bit 13 (VMXE) of CR4 is enabled after the module load function, but during the module unload function, it's no longer set.

Is there a kernel module that would periodically reset VMXE? I have kvm.ko and kvm_intel.ko unloaded when running this code, and the Intel emulation BIOS settings have been enabled, and the CPU supports VMX.

As per ([Modifying control register in kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954917/modifying-control-register-in-kernel-module)), I tried adding `on_each_cpu` to set VMXE on each CPU core, but it didn't help.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at Linux Cross-Reference to attempt to trace all places where CR4 may be changed? Or a simple grep of full kernel sources would od the same thing. such approch would typically help me answering most of questions "where is X changed?" or at least helps to understand where one should put extra debug messages to be able to trace execution dynamically.

Comment: Recently, in my VMX testing, I also met this problem.  My case is set VMXE=1 in CR4 should be done in module_init(), instead of in another function to initialize VMXON/VMCS regions, otherwise, the first call of vmlaunch will fail with instruction error of 8 (invalid host state), next calls of vmlaunch or vmresume will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel is not deliberately clearing CR4.VMXE. Rather, Linux caches the value of CR4 and uses the cache instead of reading the register, perhaps for performance reasons. Since you didn't change that cache, the next time the kernel tries to clear a bit in CR4, it will restore the VMXE bit from the cache, clearing it to zero. If your driver had established a VMXON region, you would instead have seen a kernel panic when the kernel inadvertently cleared CR4.VMXE with an active VMXON region.

There isn't anything that I'm aware of that periodically resets CR4 bits. However, TLB shootdowns are somewhat common, and if any of the pages being invalidated are global, the *only* way to do that is to clear CR4.PGE. I don't know why global pages would be frequently invalidated, but I know a coworker of mine had to debug an issue that started around the 4.4.0 series kernels caused by CR4.PGE being cleared, so it definitely happens with some frequency.

The proper way to enable CR4 feature bits is the same way the kernel itself does it e.g. in /arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c:

```
static __always_inline void setup_smep(struct cpuinfo_x86 *c)
{
    if (cpu_has(c, X86_FEATURE_SMEP))
        cr4_set_bits(X86_CR4_SMEP);
}
```

This ends up calling this function:

```
void cr4_update_irqsoff(unsigned long set, unsigned long clear)
{
    unsigned long newval, cr4 = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);

    lockdep_assert_irqs_disabled();

    newval = (cr4 & ~clear) | set;
    if (newval != cr4) {
        this_cpu_write(cpu_tlbstate.cr4, newval);
        __write_cr4(newval);
    }
}
```

Notice that it doesn't call `__read_cr4()` but rather `this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4)`. This is the cache that must be updated if you want the kernel to stop disabling CR4.VMXE.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Every now and then I think about this question and now it has an answer! That makes a lot of sense though - caching cr4 isn't unreasonable and I probably should have looked for the Linux cr4 facilities instead of trying to roll my own there. Live and learn!

Comment: I'm not sure what's reasonable and what's not. I'm not aware of any documentation stating that the kernel intends to own the CR4 register. You just have to know. Reading CR4 is relatively expensive but not terrible; I measured 1/18 cycles throughput on a Coffee Lake Xeon vs. 3/cycle for a normal memory read. Reading an MSR costs over 300 cycles, but the patch set to support RDFSBASE and RDGSBASE wasn't merged until something like 2020, almost a full decade after the instructions were introduced. I would guess that avoiding WRMSR improves performance more than avoiding a read of CR4.

Comment: On the subject of setting CR4.VMXE, it's complicated because there is no well-defined scheme for cooperation amongst hypervisors. KVM uses the kernel interface to set the bit, loads its VMXON region, and leaves both in place. Some other hypervisor, I forget which, disables interrupts, enables CR4.VMXE, etc., and then restores machine state before reenabling interrupts and returning control to the kernel. The latter is slower but allows multiple hypervisors to cooperate. It also doesn't require using the kernel interface to set CR4.VMXE.